# Change a property of a component from another component and render it in the html in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 3 components 'starter-left-side', 'starter-content', 'camera'. 1 service 'generalParameters'. In the generalParameters, I have 2 properties; 'contentHeader' & contentDescription which has default string values respectively.

Upon initialization of the starter-content, I get these values from the generalParameters and render it in starter-content.html. When I want to go to the camera.component, I just click on the link to the camera.component via the starter-left-side also, I have a method in the starter-left-side that sets the property value of the generalProperties as soon as the link is clicked so it can be used by the starter-content again.

I can successfully change the values in the generalProperties but the problem is, it is not rendered in the starter-component anymore. I do not know on which time of the life cycle hooks should I get the values from the generalProperties again so it can be rendered in the starter-content.html.

**generaParameters.service.ts**

```
contentHeader: string;
contentDescription: string;

constructor() {
  this.contentHeader = "Dashboard";
  this.contentDescription = "This is your dashboard";
}
```

**starter-content.component.html**

```
<h1>
  {{pageHeader}}
  <small>{{description}}</small>
</h1>
```

**starter-content.component.ts**

```
pageHeader: string;
description: string;

constructor(
  private gp: GeneralparametersService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.pageHeader = this.gp.contentHeader;
  this.description = this.gp.contentDescription;
}
```

**starter-left-side.component.ts**

```
setContent(header, description) {
  this.gp.contentHeader = header;
  this.gp.contentDescription = description;
}
```

**starter-left-side.component.html**

```
<li class="active"><a href="avascript:void(0);" (click)="setContent('Camera', 'Using Camera')" [routerLink]="['camera']"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Camera</span></a></li>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: if you console are you getting any value?

Comment: When I click the link for the camera, I can print the words. It's just not being rendered in the starter-content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Subject or BehaviorSubject in your Service. Thus, all components get updated when the value changes:

**generaParameters.service.ts**

```
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';     

contentHeader: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('Dashboard');
contentDescription: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('This is your dashboard');

constructor() {}

public getContentHeader(): Observable<string> {
    return this.contentHeader.asObservable();
}

public setContentHeader(value: string): void {
    this.contentHeader.next(value);
}

public getContentDescription(): Observable<string> {
    return this.contentDescription.asObservable();
}

public setContentDescription(value: string): void {
    this.contentDescription.next(value);
}
```

**starter-content.component.html**

```
<h1>
  {{pageHeader}}
  <small>{{description}}</small>
</h1>
```

**starter-content.component.ts**

```
pageHeader: string;
description: string;

constructor(
  private gp: GeneralparametersService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.gp.getContentHeader().subscribe(value => {
      this.pageHeader = value;
  });

  this.gp.getContentDescription().subscribe(value => {
      this.contentDescription = value;
  });
}
```

**starter-left-side.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.gp.getContentHeader().subscribe(value => {
      this.pageHeader = value;
   });

   this.gp.getContentDescription().subscribe(value => {
      this.contentDescription = value;
   });
}

setContent(header, description) {
  this.gp.setContentHeader(header);
  this.gp.setContentDescription(description);
}
```

**starter-left-side.component.html**

```
<li class="active"><a href="avascript:void(0);" (click)="setContent('Camera', 'Using Camera')" [routerLink]="['camera']"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Camera</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Here you go. Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution, if it solved your problem or answered your question.

Comment: It did answer my question. I just need to study on these topics "import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';     

contentHeader: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('Dashboard');
contentDescription: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('This is your dashboard');". But, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are communicating using a service you can propagate your changes using an `Subject`

When you make changes to your subject via the `gp.setContent` since your other component is *observing* the changes they will be automatically updated.

I used [pluck](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/pluck) so that we can only take the properties we need and render them separately.

See my implementation. Hope it helps!!!

**starter-left-side.component.html**

```
<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="gp.setContent('Camera', 'Using Camera')" [routerLink]="['camera']"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Camera</span></a></li>
```

***generaParameters.service.ts***

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

  private mycontent$ = new Subject();

  public content$ = this.mycontent$.asObservable();

  setContent(header, description) {
    this.content$.next({header, description});
  }
```

**starter-content.component.ts**

```
import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pageHeader$ = this.gp.content$.pipe(pluck('header'));
    this.pageDescription$ = this.gp.content$.pipe(pluck('description'));
  }
```

**starter-content.component.html**

```
<h1>
  {{pageHeader$ | async }}
  <small>{{pageDescription$ | async}}</small>
</h1>
```

Comment: This is quite good but Lynx's coding is easier to read. Thank you anyways.